# C# overriding a method with different parameters

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, overriding, subclass

I am working on an assignment that involves inheritance and overriding methods. I am supposed to create a `Ship` class and a `CruiseShip` subclass. The ship class is supposed to have two member variables, a string for the ship's name and a string for the ships build date. The class also needs a `Print` method to display that information.

The `CruiseShip` subclass is similar except that instead of a member variable for build date, it is to have an integer value for its max capacity of passengers. The subclass is supposed to override the `Ship` class's `Print` method and display only the ship name and capacity (not the date).

The issue with my code below is that I am not sure how to override the `Print` method to take a string and an integer, instead of two strings. How can I have the override method display the appropriate date?

```
public class Ship
{
    public virtual void Print(string name, string date)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The ship's name: {0}", name);
        Console.WriteLine("The ship's build date: {0}", date);
    }
}

public class CruiseShip : Ship
{
    public override void Print(string name, int capacity)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The ship's name: {0}", name);
        Console.WriteLine("The ship's passanger capacity: {0}", capacity);
    }
}

public class SeeShips
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Ship newShip = new Ship();
        newShip.Print("Generic Ship","1989");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot "override" a method and change the parameter types. Period. Since you've opted to call the method accepting two strings, the way to get your code to compile is to remove the `override` keyword.  It isn't clear what you expected to happen here, since you seem to want to call the base class method either way, given that that is the only method here that accepts two strings. Can you explain what you wanted to happen beyond "it does not do what I want"?

Comment: "The CruiseShip subclass is similar except that **instead** of a member variable for build date, it is to have an integer value for its max capacity of passengers." That makes 0 sense. I can only asume you utterly missread the assignment. No other way to interpret this. "Print" that sounds like a "ToString()" method. Normal overloading.

Comment: Sure, let me try to elaborate. Based on other comments, I am not sure what a member variable is, or how to use it. I am supposed to have a `Print` method that uses these member variables to display data. I would like to have a `Ship` class that has a member variable for its name and date and a `Print` method that used the name and date variables. I would then like a `CruiseShip` subclass that has a capacity member variable and a `Print` method that overrides the one from the parent class that only prints the ship name and capacity.

Comment: You can have all that, *except* that you cannot change the types of the parameters of methods you override. Does the method *need* parameters? If you want to ask an instance to print itself, shouldn't all the data to print come from the object itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are creating stateless classes, which is essentially what you are not supposed to do in this assignment.

Imagine I create one of your ships:

```
var myShip = new Ship();
```

Ok great, so... what's special about this ship? I'd say nothing... the ship has no info tied to it, they are all the same. You need to find a mechanism that actually stores information inside your ship, AKA *state*:

```
public class Ship
{
    //these should be properties or
    //readonly variables but thats for later
    public string name; 
    public string date;
}
```

Ok, now you can create a `Ship` and give it some state:

```
var myShip = new Ship();
myShip.name = "My Ship";
myShip.date = "Yesterday";
```

Great! Now we *do* have an interesting ship in our hands; it has a *name* and a *date*.

Furthermore, now the virtual method `Print` doesn't need any information passed into it (arguments) because it can fetch the state from the ship from which the method is invoked:

```
public class Ship
{
     ....
     public virtual string Print() {
        Console.WriteLine("The ship's name: {0}", name);
        Console.WriteLine("The ship's build date: {0}", date); }
```

You see how that works?

From here, you should be able to figure out how to subclass `CruiseShip` and override `Print` and make it do what you want.

Subjects you will definitely want to read about:

1. Constructors and initializing state
2. Why properties instead of public member fields
3. Read only member fields and properties and immutable types

Answer (score 0):

The Print methods shall take their data from member variables, so no parameters required

Comment: Perhaps I am not clear on exactly what a member variable is then. Is it defined just like a normal variable? And how is it's value passed to the method?

Comment: A class consists of data and behaviour (methods). You declare the data (member variables) within the class as e.g. public string ShipName { get; set; }. Methods of the class have access to these.

Comment: @ZL4892 Yeah you definitely don't get what a member variable is. It's a variable thats part of the class body. also called field.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "override" a method and change the parameter types.

But you can do something like that:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Ship newShip1 = new Ship(){Name ="MyShip1", Date=DateTime.Now.ToString()};
    CruiseShip newShip2 = new CruiseShip(){Name ="MyShip2", Date=DateTime.Now.ToString(), Capacity=4};
    
    newShip1.Print();
    newShip2.Print();
}

public class Ship
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    
    public string Date {get;set;}
    
    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The ship's name: {0}", Name);
        Console.WriteLine("The ship's build date: {0}", Date);
    }
}

public class CruiseShip : Ship
{
    public int Capacity {get;set;}
    
    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The ship's name: {0}", Name);
        Console.WriteLine("The ship's passanger capacity: {0}", Capacity);
    }
}
```